# sort a document library by current logged in user

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is there any chance to write a sort expression to sort the items in document library by logged in user.

I want show all the documents and documents uploaded by the current logged in user will display first remaining documents will display next in same view itself.

Answer (score 1):

Create two web parts with view filters with Assigned To Equals "[Me]" and one with Assigned To Not Equal "[Me]"

The [Me] token is the current user.

You can add useful headers like "My Shared Documents" and "Others Shared Documents"